# how to use Elmah.Contrib.WebApi 1.0.9?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, elmah

I am working on WEB API project. I want to implement global error handling and i choose ELMAH for that.

On googling i found i can implement ELMAH in WEB API with Elmah.Contrib.WebApi package.

So i installed the package Elmah.Contrib.WebApi and as written in [author's github site](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi) i registered it.

so my global.asax looks like following.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageLoggingHandler());

    }
```

but it does not seem to work. i also tried to find documentation on how to implement this package in project but could not find it.

can someone help me so i can get work that pacakge?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Web API 2**, you should use the new exception logger:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
        ...
    }
}
```

Also shown in this post:

http://blog.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-web-api/

(without the elmah.io package if you are using another log store)

Comment: i installed elmah.io package but still same effect but still same effect and error has been thrown after elmah implementation it should have been logged not thrown

Comment: You don't need to install the elmah.io package. That's only if you want to use elmah.io as log store. Did you add the line: config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());

Comment: BTW ELMAH wont catch the error in order for it not being shown to the user. It only listens for errors and logs if any.